# Is there way to get intellisense when editing AML files in SandCastle?

Tags: sandcastle, chm

I am using sandcastle to auther my help files.

Editing AML files is painful because there as no intellisense support - unlike, say, ASP.NET or XAML in Visual Studio.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread:

MAML IntelliSense

http://docproject.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=29833

HTH